# What exactly makes a story interesting? (philosophical)

Tags: creative-writing, ideas, philosophy

So I am trying to write a story for a game.
I am more of a systems guy so this is uncharted territory.

I try not to follow examples ("make terrible things happen to the characters") but rather the philosophical aspects as that opens up a lot of possibilities in how a game can be made fun.

- What makes us as humans interested in reading about the suffering of the characters in the story? Not necessarily suffering but always facing problems or some kind of conflict. (It reminds me of people watching gladiators or boxers)
- What keeps you reading? I mean, why do you care of what happens next, if you really just wanted to know only that you could let yourself get spoilered. So there is more then that.
- Do you enjoy happy endings? Why exactly or why not? (unfortunate endings might appeal to some because of the realism, but that of course gives the question: What do you read storys for? To learn from them or for the enjoyment?)

I can't really answer these questions myself, because I don't read stories all that much. I think that this is the best forum to ask these questions, because I assume you had to answer some o these questions for yourself before.

Comment: There is no real answer for this, and a philosophical look into why stories are interesting would be a huge discussion that isn't suitable for a stack exchange site. Personally, I think that people enjoy stories because there are some elements in them, that they themselves want to believe in. So make sure to identify who you are targeting and see what they like.

Comment: Hi RIJIK, welcome to Writing (Beta) on SE.  Your question is very broad and non-specific.  This forum works best for questions that ask a single thing.  You can improve the quality of the responses to your question by focusing it on a single topic.  You can post multiple questions to the site.   I think you've described your situation very clearly, and that is a great start.  But your question reads like many many different questions, and that is discouraged since the answers become much more opinion driven than question driven.

Comment: If you are looking for general information on storytelling then the online lectures by Brandon Sanderson are an excellent place to start. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N4ZDBOc2tX8

Comment: @Shadowzee Can you maybe point me to a place where these questions belong? EDL pointed me to a lecture nthat might help, but is there also a forum of sorts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What makes us as humans interested in reading about the suffering of the characters in the story?

In fiction, they don't expect that suffering to **last,** at least not for the main characters or heroes they are identifying with. The suffering **justifies** what the heroes must do to overcome whatever evil or hardship they face. It is not watching gladiators or boxers, those fighters are **just** fighting, they are not defending any principles, not defending or rescuing the innocent, not sacrificing themselves for their children or for humanity, they aren't fighting for any **reason** other than to win.

We want to see heroes that sacrifice themselves for what is **right** to defeat evil that is **wrong**.

"Evil" is the selfish premise that getting your way, in terms of wealth, sex, luxury, power, or ideology justifies **any** harm it causes to **innocent** others: Injury, death, disease, misery, grief or despair. Obviously there are degrees of evil.

"Right" is the opposite altruistic premise, that avoiding and preventing harm to **innocents** is worthy and admirable, and actually risking harm yourself to prevent harms to innocents is heroic.

> What keeps you reading? I mean, why do you care of what happens next, if you really just wanted to know only that you could let yourself get spoilered. So there is more than that.

What keeps you reading is indeed wondering what happens next, but also you want to follow the adventure. Spoilers **spoil** the adventure of vicariously being the hero (or beside the hero) and going through their experiences, emotions, suffering and epiphanies. **Spoiler Alert:** In real life, in the end we all die, every one of us. But that doesn't really matter **today**; **today** we can have some fun!

The journey is what matters and builds the vicarious virtual experience, just knowing the ending doesn't provide the virtual experience. We read because the fiction presents something near to a life experience, in a few hours. We don't want the spoilers because in real life we don't know how the future will turn out, we take risks without knowing if we will win, and sometimes we don't win. We want the fiction to reflect real life (with a bias toward heroes defeating evil in the end, which is unfortunately not how real life usually turns out).

> Do you enjoy happy endings? Why exactly or why not? (unfortunate endings might appeal to some because of the realism, but that of course gives the question: What do you read stories for? To learn from them or for the enjoyment?)

I have read Hollywood studios have studied this, and find that regardless of awards, critical acclaim or anything else, happy endings outsell unhappy endings by 10 to one, or more specifically, "evil defeated" endings outsell "hero defeated" endings by 10 to one. We are looking for sacrifice, so a hero can die defeating evil, making the ultimate sacrifice, and that can still be seen as a good ending. But evil *prevailing* (unless it is in a series and a temporary victory) is not going to **sell** well, even if it wins Oscars or Book Awards or critics **love** it.

People like happy endings because they consume fiction to **escape** the real world, where mobsters and frauds and assholes and evil people in general abound and seem to operate and prevail with impunity. In **real life** children get cancer and die, they are torn apart in car wrecks by drunk drivers that get away with it, people get raped and murdered and the police do nothing about it, nor does anyone else.

In **real life** heroes don't appear, or people trying to be heroes fail or get killed without saving anybody. Corporations hide and cover up their lies and profit-seeking shortcuts that ruined innocent lives, and get away with a fine that costs them 1% of their profits. *ohhh nooo!* (ahem, high five).

We (for the most part) read fiction to escape that aspect of real life. We do want our fiction to be 'true to life' in the sense of seeming like it could really happen, that helps us immerse ourself in the story and the adventure. But we **don't** want the "realism" of heroes usually being defeated and evil winning in the end. That is not escapism, if we want to feel depressed and hopeless we can watch the news of the world on almost any night.

The truth from the real world is **crime pays.** Evil has a competitive advantage in politics, business, running religions or charities -- because the truly evil are willing to do **anything** to win, and anybody with a shred of morality is, by definition, not willing to do **anything** to win, and the more moral they are the less effective they can be.

That is the fundamental dilemma of life; being on the side of "right" is bringing a knife to a gunfight. In fiction, to be escapist, the hero with the knife needs to defeat the gunslinger, against the odds. Otherwise it isn't a happy ending, and people don't enjoy it, so they don't recommend it, or they give it a bad review and say the ending was disappointing, or they say nothing about it but recommend something else that DID have a happy ending.

Call that word of mouth or whatever you want, in the modern world we pay a lot of attention to what other people think about entertainment because we find it predictive of how much **we** will like the entertainment, and that is why sales figures are highly correlated to how much the public actually liked consuming a particular book or movie. And that is why Happy Endings outsell Unhappy Endings ten to one; a small percentage of "independents" are willing to try an entertainment first and "blind", but their reactions then become extremely important. If they say they didn't care for it, that kills the sales to the 90% of people that are more cautious and **won't** buy without any recommendation. As soon as an early independent waves them off they move on; there is a glut of other entertainment to buy that **is** recommended.

Yes, we like happy endings, and particularly in the modern world that preference will be reflected in your sales.

Comment: I'd vote for this again, too.

Comment: That is an amazing answer! It delves exactly into what I was interested in.

Answer (score 3):

**Question**: What makes a story interesting?

**Answer:** Here are the things I find make stories interesting.

1. Relationships. Think less about plot and more about how the parts (edit: the way the characters) fit together in helpful vs. harmful ways. Balance the relationships. Some good, some bad, show both. Conflict, but also support.
2. Time. Good stories give us characters that have had a *past* and that yearn toward a *future*. Storytelling limited to 'in the moment' risks portraying characters that do not have this sort of dimensionality. *We are all a product of the past and we all have dreams*. Characters can and should, too.
3. Multi-sensate experience. Smell, sound, etc.

Although there are lots of parts to a good story, I think these are some of the really important bits that sometime get overlooked.

(Page-turning is down to conflict and suspense and well-crafted writing. Satisfying endings should fulfill the contract and need not be happy. But this feels like we're starting to open a can of worms.)

Edit (to comment): "isn't how the parts fit together the same as the plot?" To my mind, the way *events* fit together, one leading to the next, is plot. The way people fit together--adversary, loyal best friend, mentor, lover, commander, and so on--is less linear, more fluid, and sort of 'chewier' to a story. Example: when a lover turns into a stalker, that's a plot point, but also a shift in relationship between two characters. And, a story can have a complete arc but if it lacks any friendship it might feel less realized than otherwise. That's the sort of thing I mean. I like stories that have a breadth of developed relationships in addition to developed characters.

Comment: I'd like to vote for this again.

Comment: I have a question regarding "Relationships": isn't how the parts fit together the same as the plot? The other two points I think are mainly to convey realism, where as "Time" would create a realistic reason for conflict.